# query-based JDBC Source connector Kafka

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a legacy data base that has  a primary key column to be string ( yeah I know ). I want to do an `increment` dumping mode from the postgres DB into kafka topics using JDBC kafka Source Connector

Below is my attempt to recreate the problem

```
create table test(
id varchar(20) primary key,
name varchar(10) 
);

INSERT INTO test(
    id, name)
VALUES ('1ab', 't'),
('2ab', 't'),
('3ab', 't')
```

My config

```
{"name" : "test_connector",
    "config" : {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://12.34.5.6:5432/",
        "connection.user": "user",
        "connection.password": "password",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "topic.prefix": "incre_",
        "mode": "incrementing",
        "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
        "query" :"SELECT cast(replace(id, 'ab','') as integer) as id , name from test ORDER BY id ASC",
        "incrementing.column.name":"id",
        "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry_url.com",
        "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry_url.com",
        "offset.flush.timeout.ms": 2000,

    }
}
```

After I posted the config , the status was `RUNNING` when I did a HTTP curl . There is also no error log in the worker's log when I checked it 
There is also no data in the kafka topic when I tried to do a console-consumer 
I also tried several other combination like adding in `"table.whitelist": "test"`.

Another thing i tried was following these two links 
https://rmoff.net/2018/05/21/kafka-connect-and-oracle-data-types/ 
https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-jdbc-source-connector but none help , even the smart trick that was suggested like `SELECT * from (SELECT id, name from test where ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after a few hours playing with different configuration. I come back to the official [document](https://docs.confluent.io/2.0.0/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/index.html) and realised this

> Use a custom query instead of loading tables, allowing you to join data from multiple tables. As long as the query does not include its own filtering, you can still use the built-in modes for incremental queries (in this case, using a timestamp column). Note that this limits you to a single output per connector and because there is no table name, the topic “prefix” is actually the full topic name in this case.

So the key is that `"topic.prefix": "incre_test"`

Follow up on the previous setting, the proper config should be

```
{"name" : "test_connector",
    "config" : {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://12.34.5.6:5432/",
        "connection.user": "user",
        "connection.password": "password",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "topic.prefix": "incre_test",
        "mode": "incrementing",
        "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
        "query" :"SELECT cast(replace(id, 'ab','') as integer) as id , name from test ORDER BY id ASC",
        "incrementing.column.name":"id",
        "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry_url.com",
        "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry_url.com",
        "offset.flush.timeout.ms": 2000,

    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't came across this in documentation, but its important point to remember when using query

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you cannot use your `varchar id` in `incrementing` mode because it is not an incrementing column/type. According to [Confluent Docs](https://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/jdbc_connector.html#incremental-query-modes),

> **Incrementing Column:** A single column containing a unique ID for each row, where newer rows are guaranteed to have larger IDs, i.e. an
>   `AUTOINCREMENT` column. Note that this mode can only detect new rows.
>   Updates to existing rows cannot be detected, so this mode should only
>   be used for immutable data. One example where you might use this mode
>   is when streaming fact tables in a data warehouse, since those are
>   typically insert-only.